# Set deliberate trigger time

Tags: google-apps-script

I set up a script to run hourly. The problem I have is that I want it to run every hour at XX:00 o'clock, but it updates at XX:17.

How do I get it to run at XX:00?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  Here's what they say in the documentation `The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse before the trigger fires again.` Here's the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: thanks. I guess I'll just have to keep on trying till it randomly chooses XX:00

Comment: I think you could setup a trigger one hour early and wait until it's setup and then run a delayed trigger and get yourself pretty close.

Comment: I guess [nearMinute()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyminutesn) will bring it much closer.